# Mockito Tests Pass individually but fail as part of a suite

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-test

I have a case where my mockito tests all pass individually but can fail when run as part of a testing suite.
I am using mockito version 2.9.0

My test class is as follows

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.BDDMockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.cache.CacheServices;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(value={"classpath:generalConfig/generalConfigMocks-context.xml"})
public class GeneralConfigAPIClientTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    CacheServices cacheServices; 

    @Autowired
    IGeneralConfigServices generalConfigServices;

    @Autowired 
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    /**
     * Set up the test context, initialize the mockMvc.
     * */
    @Before 
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();       
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyGeneralConfigCache_FailureFalseReturned() throws Exception {

        BDDMockito.given(cacheServices.emptyCacheContents(BDDMockito.anyString())).willReturn(false);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/generalConfig/emptyGeneralConfigCache"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())     
                .andReturn();

        BDDMockito.verify(cacheServices, BDDMockito.times(1)).emptyCacheContents(BDDMockito.anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyGeneralConfigCache_SuccessTrueReturned() throws Exception {
        BDDMockito.given(cacheServices.emptyCacheContents(BDDMockito.anyString())).willReturn(true);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/generalConfig/emptyGeneralConfigCache"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())     
                .andReturn();

        BDDMockito.verify(cacheServices, BDDMockito.times(1)).emptyCacheContents(BDDMockito.anyString());
    }

    }
```

The contents of generalConfig/generalConfigMocks-context.xml are as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com..config" />

    <bean id="generalConfigServices" class="org.mockito.BDDMockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.config.IGeneralConfigServices"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="cacheServices" class="org.mockito.BDDMockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.cache.CacheServices"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

A sample error response I get from running my tests is as follows

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
cacheServices.emptyCacheContents(
    <any string>
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.config.GeneralConfigAPIClientTest.testEmptyGeneralConfigCache_SuccessTrueReturned(GeneralConfigAPIClientTest.java:65)
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.config.GeneralConfigAPIClient.callEmptyGeneralConfigCache(GeneralConfigAPIClient.java:34)

    at com.config.GeneralConfigAPIClientTest.testEmptyGeneralConfigCache_SuccessTrueReturned(GeneralConfigAPIClientTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Can anyone offer any insights as to why my tests are passing individually but failing as a group

Comment: Tr using `@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`

Comment: You're doing `verify(cacheServices, BDDMockito.times(1))` in both methods meaning it can only be invoked once. It is the same object so it gets invoked twice when you run the full suite.

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` produces quite a bit of overhead, I would suggest solving the problem without that, for example by resetting the offending mocks after the test. See the answer that Chi Coung Le posted below for more possibilities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reason: your test load one application context with bean mock inside. The bean mocks are dirty after any test. You have a dirty application context also.

Solution: you have to clean bean mock. Using Mockito.reset(mocks) after each test. I've found sth similar: [How to clean up mocks in spring tests when using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164123/how-to-clean-up-mocks-in-spring-tests-when-using-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

I am late in the game, but thought that this could be useful for people that are still experiencing the same issue(source:https://reflectoring.io/clean-unit-tests-with-mockito/):

```
class CityServiceImplTest {

  // System under Test (SuT)
  private CityService cityService;

  // Mock
  private CityRepository cityRepository;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    cityRepository = Mockito.mock(CityRepository.class);
    cityService = new CityServiceImpl(cityRepository);
  }

  // Test cases omitted for brevity.

}
```

With this approach, I eliminated the @SpringBootTest annotation altogether and made the test class very light weight.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem too and solved the problem like this;

Added these 3 annotations to my test classs:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none"
})
@SpringBootTest
```

Created Mocks with:

```
@InjectMocks
private ImplService service;

@Mock
private MailService mailService;
```

In the set up:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        LockAssert.TestHelper.makeAllAssertsPass(true);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // In case if you are using "environment" in your  
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "environment", "testEnvironment");
        ....
    }
```