# Can we make Spring Boot Test and Spring Test reset mocks implicitly?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

Can we make Spring reset `@MockBean` and `@Mock` annotated things explicitly?
I mean are there any magic annotations which forces reset on things after Test method is evaluated.

PS. I don't want to explicitly write `reset()` in `@AfterTest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean up mocks in spring tests when using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164123/how-to-clean-up-mocks-in-spring-tests-when-using-mockito)